# SQL Query for specific conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Need assistance with SQL statement for below condition.
Have 3 columns in a table (TableName), Sno (unique records), Name ( there are multiple records that can have same name) , Condition (True,False) .
Need to extract All records if the last record true only.

Have tried below query

```
select Sno(Max),Name,Condition 
from TableName 
where Conditon = 'True' 
group by Name,Conditon;
```

Expected: If last record (SNo (Max)) has value = true (condition column) then return this record, else no records displayed.

Actual: All records are displayed including true and false condition

Comment: What do you mean with "last record", I don't see an order by ? And what is `Sno(Max)` in the SELECT list?

Comment: Please add sample data and expected results.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: A few rows of sample data and the expected result will go a long way for us to understand what exactly do you need.

Comment: Last record meaning,  in my example if i select * TableName, the results return Sno (1,2,3,4,5,6), Name (Prasan,Prasan,Prasan,Joakim,Joakim,Joakim) and Condition (True,True,False,True,True,True ) ,  hence I am expecting results having 6,Joakim,True  (as last record is true here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.
If table is like this:
[image]

[It's recommended to use `tinyint(1)` as Boolean in MySQL.]

You can use this query:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM `TableName` a
LEFT JOIN `TableName` b ON(a.`Sno` < b.`Sno`
                           AND a.`Name` = b.`Name`)
WHERE a.`Conditon` = 1
  AND b.`Sno` IS NULL
```

to get this result:
[image]

This way will work more effective than using an inner sub-query. Especially in large tables.

Comment: Yes this is the exact result i am expecting, but could we do with more simpler queries, i mean without using join condition ?

Comment: @PrasanShetty This way will work more effective than using an inner sub-query. Especially in large tables.

Comment: This query has helped me get the required results. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for that:

```
SELECT Sno, Name, Condition 
FROM TableName 
WHERE Conditon = 'True' AND Sno=(SELECT MAX(Sno) FROM TableName);
```

Beware of types: if 'Condition' column is `Boolean` WHERE clause should be

```
WHERE Condition IS TRUE AND ...
```

Comment: With this i am getting only one record. I am looking for all records in which the last record is true (i.e. Condition=True)

Comment: For example if i select * TableName, the results return Sno (1,2,3,4,5,6), Name (Prasan,Prasan,Prasan,Joakim,Joakim,Joakim) and Condition (True,True,False,True,True,True ) ,  i am expecting results having 6,Joakim,True (as last record is true here)  ,  condition column is not boolean

Comment: I get only one record, but in my table i have multiple records which has Condition Column value as True for Max Sno(last record)

Comment: ok, then question is not clear to me. If you want to get quality answers, provide detailed questions: I suggest you to modify your original question providing a data sample set including the situation you mention, and the expected results.

Comment: The comment by izem above which is the exact results i am looking for, would it it be possible to get it by using more simpler queries (without using join)

Answer (score 0):

Could be use a where exist  on a subquery for condition TRUE and Sno = max(Sno)

```
select  * 
from TableName 
where exist (
  select  * 
  from TableName 
  where  Condition = 'True'  
  and  Sno = (
  select  max(Sno) 
  from TableName 
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  sno IN (SELECT Sno(max) 
               FROM   tablename 
               GROUP  BY NAME) 
       AND condition = 'true'
```